# Can an unintentional murderer leave Ir Miklat for Shalosh Regalim?

Tags: halacha, murder, masei, city-of-refuge, shalosh-regalim

We learn in Parshas Masei about a person who unintentionally murders another.

The halacha is that the unintentional murderer is to flee to one of the Arei Miklat (Cities of Refuge), and stay there until the current Kohen Gadol passes away. If the unintentional murderer leaves the Ir Miklat, the Go'el Hadam (avenger of blood) is permitted to kill the Rotze'ach (murderer), and will be patur (exempt) from judgment. (See Bamidbar 35:21-28.)

Since the Rotze'ach is not allowed to leave the Ir Miklat until the Kohen Gadol's death, what does he do during the Shalosh Regalim, when it is obligatory that every Jewish man aged 13 and older appear in Jerusalem to present a korban?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.8b.9

Comment: Rotzeach 7:8, makos 2:7

Answer (score 13):

He stays in his *Ir Miklat*, in all cases even to save a life, as the Rambam explains in [Hilchot Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 7:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088923/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-Seven.htm)

> **A person who was exiled to a city of refuge should never leave his
>   city of refuge, not even to perform a mitzvah** or to deliver testimony
>   - neither testimony involving monetary matters, nor testimony involving a capital case. He should not leave even if he can save a
>   life by delivering testimony, or he can save a person from gentiles,
>   from a river, from a fire or from an avalanche. This applies even if
>   he is a person like Yoav ben Tz'ruyah, upon whom the salvation of the
>   entire Jewish people may depend. **He should never leave the city of
>   refuge until the death of the High Priest. If he departs, he has
>   allowed for his death, as explained.**