# Does an Ir Miklat citizen man have property?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, golus-exile, city-of-refuge, shalosh-regalim

Can (does) one who has murdered and must go to a refuge city own property there?

Specifically real estate, this would make a difference regarding his obligation to come to the temple three times a year. Although he is exempt from doing any Mitzvah which would require him to taking leave of the city, according to the Talmud ([Rebbi Ami, Pesachim 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.8b.9)) if one does not have property he is exempt from the pilgrimage.

I can see two sides to this. Perhaps this is another reason he is exempt, since he cannot own land, or perhaps he is required to appoint a proxy of sorts (and then this is also a broader question of appointing a proxy for other obligations he cannot leave for per Mishnah Makos 2:7 and Rozteach 7:8 but - why shouldn’t he be able to do good from behind bars, if he can?).

Comment: [Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106256/16706) is a related question.

Comment: Why are you limiting it to men?  The regalim nafka mina is for men, but the broader question is for men and women.

Comment: @Heshy didn’t intend for that meaning, it was more stylistic

Comment: "Can (does) one who has murdered and must go to a refuge city own property there? Specifically real estate, this would make a difference regarding his obligation to come to the temple three times a year." It *could* make that difference. He may, of course, own land elsewhere.

Comment: @msh210 well, let’s say he doesn’t. Or, can he?